# Azure: Is there any vulnerability BETWEEN Web Apps?

Tags: security, azure, azure-web-app-service

I been wondering how secure/dangerous could be to run a PHP WebApp (WebApp-A) in Azure when there is another WebApp (WebApp-B that could be a .Net app) running on the same Azure subscription.

Could WebApp-A run some malicious script and affect the server instance of WebApp-B?

Comment: Your title makes it sound like you have discovered a vulnerability. You should rephrase it as a question.

Comment: You are right, I'll fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to give a blanket-statement answer regarding malicious scripts, attack surfaces, etc. There are many vulnerabilities showing up daily (which have nothing to do with web apps - just attacks in general).

That said: Every web app in Azure is going to have its own sandbox with its own files, etc. The only thing shared between web apps? The app service plan hosting the web app(s) (you may have multiple web apps on an app service plan). But the only thing they share are things like CPU. Everything from a *code* standpoint is isolated.

You'd need to take explicit steps to grant access across web apps (e.g. add them to the same vnet).